# ReactJS, how to copy json object to another identifying value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have json data like this:

```
[{"TICKER":"APPL","ASK":192.12345,"BID":193.54321,"ISCHANGED":"NO"},
{"TICKER":"TSLA","ASK":318.98765,"BID":319.56789,"ISCHANGED":"NO"}]
```

On component update with new data I would like to compare/map the previous and the new one data and to identify changes using "ISCHANGED":"YES". Ticker is the Key, Bid/Ask - changing values.

Thanks

UPDATED with the example code:

```
    this.state = {
        quote: {
            ticker: '',
            ask: '',
            bid: '',
            isChanged: ''
        }

handleQuoteFetched (data) {

    // here Im looking for a way to compare data and quote 
    // and identify values changes and set isChanged Yes/No

    this.setState({
        quote: data
    })
}

render () {

    //...
        <td className={quote.isChanged === 'Yes'?this.state.classCSSHighlight:''}>
            {quote.rateBid}>
        </td>
```

}

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please elaborate with an appropriate example

Comment: You can use componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) and compare this.props with nextProps

Comment: Thanks. I've identified prev and new data. Now the question is how to compare the arrays row by row and to set the result in to new.isChanged

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `setState` callback function.

```
this.setState((prevState, newState) => {
  // do comparison here
})
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me to move step forward. But the data is array with multiple rows. I would like to identify every individual row change.

Comment: First of all, why would you want to do that?

Comment: To highlight values changes.

Comment: Thanks again FewFlyBy, but how to for-each simultaniously the two arrays? I need code or third party function that can compare values row by row and set the result as isChanged flag (property of the object). Still searching for some smart way.

Comment: Can you show me the output of the answer above? by gg?

Comment: The result is like this: ....
`15:{ticker: "APPL", bid: 195, ask: 193, isChanged: "false"}
16:{ticker: "TSLA", bid: 313, ask: 310, isChanged: "false"}
isChanged:"true"
__proto__:Object`.

Comment: Now thanks for your help, I am aware how to catch up the process of transition from previous to new state. So now the problem is how to copy the new quotes to the component state but apply the condition element by element if new bid/ask !== current bid/ask and as result set isChanged true/false. As a final option will write a function for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lodash.isEqual` function to do a deep comparison between 2 values.

```
handleQuoteFetched (data) {

    // here Im looking for a way to compare data and quote 
    // and identify values changes and set isChanged Yes/No

    this.setState(prevState => {
        const nextState = _.isEqual(prevState.quote, data) ? {} : {...data, ISCHANGED: true}
        return nextState  
    })
}
```

Comment: Actualy, isChanged property is part of the object quote/data. (quote.isChanged). I've played the code, but unfortunately no success yet. Your code sets one global isChanged property. I need isChanged flag for each row of the quote array. Changed rows with true, unchanged with false.

Comment: In your question you have one object and i worked with one object. You can modify it and map an array and check equality of each item in array.